# Dynamically changing Webkit filter values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was struggling to change the value of

```
-webkit-filter: grayscale(30%);
```

value dynamically using HTML5 range input and javascript.

How could i access the css webkit filter attribute using javascript ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Javascript:**

```
function changegrayscale(value) {
    document.getElementById("divID").setAttribute("style","-webkit-filter:grayscale(" + value + "%)")
}​
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="divID" onclick="changegrayscale('30')">Clcik Me</div>​​
```

**CSS:**

```
#divID {
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(70%);
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/akhurshid/Ajrpq/)

Comment: It's worth noting that using setAttribute as described here will completely overwrite the style attribute of the element, throwing away any unrelated styles that had previously been set.  A preferable answer would be one which allowed -webkit-filter to be programmatically adjusted in isolation.  If I work out how to do that, I'll post it :)

Comment: There is no direct way to set `--webkit-filter` property without overwriting other styles defined in the `style=...` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Try this - [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Mpx4s/1/)

```
<input type="range" min="0" max="100" step="10" id="inp" />

<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" id="img" />
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200" />​

<script>
document.getElementById("inp").addEventListener("change", function() {
    document.getElementById("img").setAttribute("style", "-webkit-filter:grayscale(" + this.value + "%)");
}, false);​
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

With jQuery you could do it like this on the '.elements':

```
function changegrayscale(value) {
  $('.elements').css({
    '-webkit-filter': 'grayscale('+value+'%)'
  });
}
```