# Javascript onmouseover and onmouseout

Tags: javascript, html, css, onmouseover, onmouseout

You can see in the headline what it is. I've four "div", and therein are each a p tag. When I go with the mouse on the first div, changes the "opacity" of the p tag of the first div. The problem is when I go on with the mouse on the second or third "div" only changes the tag "p" from the first "div". It should changes the their own "p" tags.
And it is important, that i cannot use CSS ":hover".
The problem is clear, it is that all have the same "id".
I need a javascript which does not individually enumerated all the different classes.

I' sorry for my english.
I hope you understand me.
My script:

```
<div onmouseout="normal();" onmouseover="hover();" >
    <p id="something">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal();" onmouseover="hover();" >
    <p id="something">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal();" onmouseover="hover();" >
    <p id="something">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal();" onmouseover="hover();" >
    <p id="something">LOLOL</p>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
function normal() {
var something = document.getElementById('something');
something.style.opacity = "0.5";
}
function hover() {
var something = document.getElementById('something');
something.style.opacity = "1";
```

CSS:

```
p {
    opacity: 0.5;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: An _id attribute_ should be **unique**. This _HTML_ is invalid. You seem to also be missing a `}` at the end of your _JavaScript_ and the functions `hover` and `normal` don't even target the same _Node_.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have dedicated myself, I've improved it.

Comment: Once you have valid _HTML_, consider how you want to distinguish between the first and second items. For example, pass `this` into your function call and work from it within the function. Alternatively, take some other parameter which lets you know which `<p>` to target, and pass that as an _argument_ when invoking your functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Paul S. suggests, you need to pass `this` to the function so that it knows which element it has to work on.

```
<div onmouseout="normal(this);" onmouseover="hover(this);" >
    <p>LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(this);" onmouseover="hover(this);" >
    <p>LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(this);" onmouseover="hover(this);" >
    <p>LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(this);" onmouseover="hover(this);" >
    <p>LOLOL</p>
</div>
```

And then select the child element `<p>` for the passed `<div>`. Here I select the first child `p`, i.e. the first element in the array of children of `this` element with tag `p`, that's why you see `[0]`. So if in each div you had two paragraph, then you could use e.g. `getElementsByTagName("p")[1]` to select the second `<p>`.

```
function normal(mydiv) {
    mydiv.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.opacity="0.5";
}
function hover(mydiv) {
    mydiv.getElementsByTagName("p")[0].style.opacity="1";
}
```

See the working example here: http://jsfiddle.net/mastazi/2REe5/

Comment: I've trouble with IE. If I want to put a filter yet it does not work for IE. http://jsfiddle.net/3mKFa/

Comment: I think you mistyped `contact` instead of `content` which is the parameter accepted by the function. Also you are selecting an `img` element which is not present in the html as the child of the div passed. Additionally, you are using a Webkit filter which, as far as I know, is not expected to work on IE. Finally, I'm not sure that the way you are manipulating -webkit-filter is correct, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12297350/dynamically-changing-webkit-filter-values

Answer (score 1):

Your html should be something like this:

```
<div onmouseout="normal(1);" onmouseover="hover(1);">
  <p id="something-1">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(2);" onmouseover="hover(2);">
  <p id="something-2">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(3);" onmouseover="hover(3);">
  <p id="something-3">LOLOL</p>
</div>
<div onmouseout="normal(4);" onmouseover="hover(4);">
  <p id="something-4">LOLOL</p>
</div>
```

As you can see, we have different ids for your elements, and we pass the ids through the function that we trigger with `onlouseover` and `onmouseout`.

For your javascript, your code could be something like this:

```
function normal(id) {
  var something = document.getElementById('something-'+id);
  something.style.opacity = "0.5";
}

function hover(id) {
  var something = document.getElementById('something-'+id);
  something.style.opacity = "1";
}
```

For `normal()` and `hover()` we receive an id and change the style for the current element that have this id.

Please, [check this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leonardorb/L7fdx/) that I've built for you.

Comment: I've trouble with IE. If I want to put a filter yet it does not work for IE. http://jsfiddle.net/3mKFa