# Rollover Effect: Change Picture with Mousehover

Tags: html, hover, transition, onmouseover, onmouseout

I'm trying to create a hover that will change the picture. A lot of tutorials tell me to try onmouseover and onmouseout. But Brackets (the program I use to code) isn't able to find the second picture called "test2.png". Does anybody know how I could handle the issue, preferably using only HTML.

Here are the tutorials I watched that show what I would like to achieve:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qtpa_r1ILjo

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y4RJDUI7M8Y

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Portfolio V1</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css"/>
        <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <img src="images/test1.png" onmouseover="this.src=images/test2.png" onmouseout="this.src='test1.png'" >
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need to make sure that both images exists and in the correct folder.
2. Make sure that the name is exactly the same as you write it in your code.
3. One of the problems you had is that you didn't wrap the name of the image (in `onmouseover` with quotes: `'images/test2.png'`).
4. In the `onmouseout` you set the image to `test1.png` instead of `images/test1.png`. Is it intended?

Here is a working example:

```html
<img src="https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff" onmouseover="this.src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/f00/fff'" onmouseout="this.src='https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff'" >
```

Comment: Wow! You are a genius. I'll try this and tell you if it worked.

Comment: Thank you so much! Thank you so much for your advice! Do you also know if it is possible to add a fading transition to this hover? Because it looks a bit harsh...?

Comment: To make a fading transition you would have to use two different images :) but thats for a different question.

Comment: I mean that you have to use two different `<img` tags

Comment: Ok I'll set up another question :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JavaScript to make this work. It won't work inplace like you have tried.

EDIT: It does work inplace, but you have missed the single quotes.

In the onmouseover attribute you should refer to a JavaScript function. Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20013022/javascript-onmouseover-and-onmouseout) about onmouseover for more information.

For example you could use something like this:

```
<img src="images/test1.png" onmouseover="MouseOver(this)" onmouseout="="MouseOut(this)" >
```

Now you refer to event handlers for the onmouseover and onmouseout event. However, these event handlers still need to get defined in a javascript snippet. This could get embedded in the  element like this:

```
function MouseOver(myimg) {
  myimg.src="images/test2.png";
}

function MouseOut(myimg) {
  myimg.src="images/test1.png";
}
```

Comment: Indeed it does. In that case all that is missing is the quote I guess...

Comment: Not sure that it's all that matters, other problems might be there too (check my answer...)

Comment: Because I'm very knew to JavaScript I have no clue how to run this. Can I just copy your Code into a script tag and it should work?

Answer (score 0):

I made an example with background-color, but the principle is here.

You can check the code :

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div');

window.addEventListener('mouseover', () => {
 div.style.background = 'red'
})
```

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: green;
  transition: 3s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```